# How to implement a "fax protocol"?

Tags: fax

I want to write a program that programmatically sends faxes. Or receives faxes. **But not with a modem.** I guess I'm trying to write a fax simulator. Everything that the hardware does, I want to do using software.

There are a billion SO questions on the topic, but they either suggest an online service to use or they point me to a library, which talks to my computer's modem. So here are my specific questions:

1. When I send a fax, I can hear the warbling on the telephone line. This tells me that my fax machine is generating tones that are consumable by the recipient's. **What is that protocol?** Is there an RFC which specifies how a "pixel" is converted to a "frequency"? **Do the machines communicate back and forth, or is it one-way?**
2. If we can agree that a fax machine translates sound frequencies to images, then one ought to be able to write a program which takes an MP3 of a fax transmission and outputs a graphic. **What do I need to know in order to do this?**

Are these questions based on any flawed assumptions? Where should I start so that I can accomplish goal #2 from above?

Comment: It's kind of liking trying to write a program by drawing a relation between its output and it's hexadecimal representation. Sure, it's technically sound, but you'll have your work cut out for you ... start, I suppose, by investigating the relevant AT commands for the relevant device/protocol.

Comment: @poundifdef - Did you ever solve this? We need to do something similar.

Answer (score 8):

Actually in modem a chip called "DSP => Digital Signal Processing" is responsible to convert audio signals into digital DATA. and same can be done with a software library. there is already an open source DSP library called SpanDSP developed by "Steve Underwood" http://www.soft-switch.org/.

You can build your own application while using SpanDSP library, but it is wise to use some existing implementation of SpanDSP. Currently SpanDSP is implemented in open source FreeSwitch, CallWeaver and Asterisk PBX systems.

But if you only want to send and receive faxes without bothering low level development then try out [ICTFAX Open Source FAX system](http://www.ictfax.org/).

Answer (score 6):

The fax specifications you would need are ITU T4 and T30, which costs lots of money and are almost wilfully difficult to understand, and they'll refer you to the various modem standard for how the actual 'warbling' is done.

If you're hoping for something free/easy like an RFC, then you should probably give up now.

If you did want to decode an audio file, you would need to view that as two completely separate tasks - firstly decoding the tones to a data stream (build several soft-modems, for the various ways fax machines can agree to communicate), and then secondly decoding the data-stream to pixels (write a fax machine's software).

You are not fundamentally wrong that a fax machine converts light and dark into sound and then back again, or that it's possible to eavesdrop on a conversation between two fax machines and recover the image (either in real-time or via some kind of capture file, though I'm not sure that MP3 would work), but I suspect you've hugely, hugely underestimated the amount of work involved.

Comment: These days, both T.4 and T.30 [are freely available](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-T/en).

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fax

has plenty of background.

The ITU protocols are very involved, IIRC the exact specifications are not free.